# Getting error I don't understand in my template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

When I run 'python manage.py runserver' I get an error, and I can't figure out what the ptoblem is.

error message:
'Manager' object is not iterable

This is what it shows:

```
51  <div class="row">
52      <div class="ads">
53          {% for ad in ad_item %}
54              {% ifequal ad.redirect 'False' %}
55                  <img src="{{ ad.pic }}"></img>
56              {% endifequal %}
57              {% ifnotequal ad.redirect 'False' %}
58                  <a href="{{ ad.redirect }}"><img src="{{ ad.pic }}"></img></a>
59              {% endifnotequal %}
60          {% endfor %}
61      </div>
62  </div>
```

This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from videos.models import video, ad
from django.template import RequestContext

def show_vid (request, pk, pkv):
    video_ = get_object_or_404(video, pk=pk)
    ad_item = ad.objects
    return render (request, 'video.html', {'video_': video_, 'ad_item': ad_item})
```

This is my template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="ads">
        {% for ad in ad_item %}
            {% ifequal ad.redirect 'False' %}
                <img src="{{ ad.pic }}"></img>
            {% endifequal %}
            {% ifnotequal ad.redirect 'False' %}
                <a href="{{ ad.redirect }}"><img src="{{ ad.pic }}"></img></a>
            {% endifnotequal %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

What's the error, and what do I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.objects` is a `Manager`, not a `QuerySet`, and these are not iterable. You should work with `.all()`:

```
def show_vid (request, pk, pkv):
    video_ = get_object_or_404(video, pk=pk)
    ad_item = ad.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'video.html', {'video_': video_, 'ad_item': ad_item})
```

You probably might also want to rename `ad` to `Ad` and `video` to `Video`, since models, just like any class, normally is named in *PerlCase*, not <s>snake_case</s>.